# How can I perform a chi-square test to do feature selection in R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, feature-selection

```
Document/Term Freq  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8     C9   Tag
D1                  0   1   3   1   1   0   0   1       0   X1
D2                  1   1   3   0   1   0   0   2       0   X2
D3                  2   0   2   0   1   0   0   0       0   X3
D4                  0   0   4   0   1   0   0   0       0   X1
D5                  0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1       1   X2
D6                  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1       1   X2
D7                  0   0   0   1   1   1   1   3       0   X3
D8                  1   0   0   0   1   2   1   0       0   X1
D9                  1   0   1   1   2   2   1   3       1   X1
```

I have a DocumentTermMatrix of the above form where D1, D2, D3.....D9 are the documents. C1, C2, C3....C9 are the terms available in all or any of the documents and the numbers are the frequencies that the term occur in the document. The values in the Tag column are the label for each document. My original DTM has around 100000 rows and 2000 features(column) and the number of unique label is around 6000. Now I want to perform chi- square test for feature selection in R. But I don't know how to do that in R and once done how to interpret the results so that I can do a feature selection based on the chi-square result.

Comment: Use the FSelector package [1]. [1] http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Manually checking each column might be an overhead you can avoid.

You can try the following approach:

Run a random forest on your term document matrix.

Look at the importance of each variable.

This should narrow your search to the most significant predictors.

Also, I would recommend trying out the RTextTools package that could potentially automate your classification needs using ensembles. I've found it to be practically the most useful for the least effort.

Comment: I know about the RTextTools pacakge. But I want understand how to do the feature selection based on the chi-square test.

Comment: The chi-square test is used when two variables being considered are both categoric in nature. In this case, your word counts are going to be numeric and have a large number of 0's typically which will violate the chi-square requirement of at least 5 in each cell. You can use an ANOVA possibly to check for relationships to a given tag.

Comment: But I have seen in many places people uses chi-squared test for text classification problem. And In RTextTools pacakge does they do any kind of feature selection before creating the container.

Comment: This is a hack you could use, but do not treat it as statistically valid. If your requirement is to rank order your predictors, simply run chisq.test(dtm[,i],tag) and store the chi-square stat in a vector. Sort this vector after iterating over each column and you have what you are looking for.